# How to change css content hover effect background color css php in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Look at the code and run it, I want to change the hover effect for the content '\00a0' background color. It has no problem to change the background-color hover effect, but it cannot change the content'\00a0' background color--from grey to green. Help, appreciate.

```css
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:40px;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content:'\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 ';
    background-color: #c7c5c5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px; 
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
 
    text-shadow:1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) :hover ~ label {
    content:'\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 ';
 
    background-color: #4bce32;/*here is what I want to change when user clikc*/
}

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ea0;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) :hover ~ label {
    content:'\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 ';
    background-color: #4bce32;/*here is what I want to change when user clikc*/
}
```

to

```
.rating:not(:checked) :hover ~ label:before {
content:'\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 ';
background-color: #4bce32;
}

.rating:not(:checked) :hover ~ label {
    background-color: #4bce32;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It could change the content color now, but only individual, I lose the effect that it keep the color change precede by that.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, do you have a way to put a white space between them with the hover?